# Are Swing MouseMoved events dispatched in input order?

Tags: java, swing, edt

I'm developing a small game engine in Java and I use Swing to collect input and display graphics. I'm having a strange bug with `MouseMoved` events and I'm wondering whether the EDT handles the inputs in a given order or not, to understand if something else is wrong with my code or not. I couldn't find any information online. This is my `mouseMoved()` method:

```
gameFrame.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        GameScene lastScene = null;
        synchronized (scenes) {
            if (scenes.size() > 0) {
                lastScene = scenes.get(scenes.size() - 1);
            }
        }
        if (lastScene != null && lastScene.isRunning()) {
            lastScene.mouseMoved((int) (e.getX() / scale), (int) (e.getY() / scale), cameraX, cameraY, scale);
        }
    }
});
```

According to `System.nanotime()` it runs in way less than a millisecond.

Comment: IMHO `MouseMoved` events that are not delivered in chronological order seem pretty useless (think for example of a freehand drawing program), so I would guess that they are always delivered in chronological order without the need to separately document it.

Comment: You can always have a look at the [`InputEvent#getWhen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#getWhen()) result

Comment: *to understand if something else is wrong with my code* - that would be my guess. For one thing there is no need for the "synchronized". Listener code executes on the EDT. The events will be processed in the order they are generated.